# typical 404 response message

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, response

I want to look like how does a `HTTP response header` looks like..
I am using PHP...
Especially i want to see a typical HTTP 404 response header..
If there is a php server array that contains all the http header info i want to find it!!
The above array has his items order by which will send it first?

Thx in advance!!

I have wireshark installed into my PC, but i don't know how to search for http response messages!!

Comment: I'm sorry, do you want to look like an HTTP response header? :-) #notfunny

Comment: Wireshark is for inspecting raw TCP exchange. You'll have better experience with HTTP proxies. Try [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i want to see how does it like..
excuse me for my english

Comment: ChrisPappas: no problem, but I couldn't resist :-) See my another comment for actually *helpful* information.

Comment: @Chris Can you please convince me why in the world you want to know how HTTP implements headers and precisely the order in which they are processed ?! First of all what are you trying to accomplish, and 2nd i definitely think your solution to your problem is far far fetched so in order to get ideas we need to know what you are doing, and what does php have to do with this ?

Comment: @Danny: What's wrong with curiosity?

Comment: I want to write a `write_message()` in javascript that writes (char -- char) into the screen a typicall http 404 response message

Comment: Voting to close because the question doesn't really say what you want. Do you just want to see where the 404 status appears in the response message (it's the first line, see the spec: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-6)? Or do you want to see what people typically put into the body of a 404? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/). It's a very nice/simple header viewer. Install it, activate it, hit some url you KNOW will produce a 404, and view the response.

Simple as that.l

Answer (score 3):

The `nc(1)` netcat tool can do this pretty easily, assuming you have a web server of some sort configured:

```
$ echo -n -e "GET /does_not_exit HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n" | nc localhost 80
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/0.8.54
Date: Mon, 02 Jan 2012 02:33:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/0.8.54</center>
</body>
</html>
$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use the 404 error:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

However, most of the info you are looking for can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

and:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Those are the variables that you can use to display server info.  The header function sets the HTTP header to whatever you would like.  You can view most header info using firebug or developer tools, or whatever tools your browser comes with.

Comment: i don't want to set the header..
i want to see the header

Comment: can you write into your answer a typicall http 404 response?

Answer (score 0):

Firebug's Net tab can be helpful..

http://getfirebug.com/